# For p>>n, where p is number of predictors and n is number of observations, is n P or P+N?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, classification, mathematical-statistics, terminology

For p$\gg$n, where p is number of predictors and n is number of observations, is n P or P+N?

For example, if I am building a binary classifier, and I have 165 positive and 165 negative observations, then does n=165 (P) or does n=330 (P+N)?

This may seem like a rather trivial question but I have searched extensively for the answer and I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: n is the number of observations from all/both classes. (n=330)

Comment: If you have no definition of n, maybe n can be anything you want it be